# Javascript - Why I am getting this error when I am using ng-if in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am actually trying to show/hide a div based on user-type , suppose usertype1 will be able to see the div but usertype2 will not be able to view the div.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="rate animated rubberBand" ng-if="myCheck">
            <input type="radio" id="starRating5" name="rate" value="5" disabled>
            <label for="star5" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating4" name="rate" value="4" disabled>
            <label for="star4" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating3" name="rate" value="3" disabled>
            <label for="star3" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating2" name="rate" value="2" disabled>
            <label for="star2" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating1" name="rate" value="1" disabled>
            <label for="star1" title="text"></label>
            </div>
```

JS CODE

```
    if (userType === 'userType2')
    {
        $scope.myCheck = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.myCheck = true;
    }
```

**JS CODE BLOCK which is giving me the error**

```
    if($scope.Item.starRating === 'NULL'){
        $scope.Item.starRating = 0;
    }

    else if($scope.Item.starRating === '1'){
        document.getElementById("starRating1").checked = true;
    }

    else if($scope.Item.starRating === '2'){
        document.getElementById("starRating2").checked = true;
    }

    else if($scope.Item.starRating === '3'){
        document.getElementById("starRating3").checked = true;
    }

    else if($scope.Item.starRating === '4'){            
        document.getElementById("starRating4").checked = true;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("starRating5").checked = true;
    }
```

THE ERROR

***Cannot set property 'checked' of null***

I just want to show the div for userType1 and hide for userType2. **I am not using JQuery.**

**UPDATE**

the only problem I am getting with Pengyy's solution - the problem is fixed with userType1 in which the div show but now I am facing problem with userType2 in which the div should not display. Here in userType2 inspite of myCheck being false and irrespective of whether ng-show or both ng-cloak and ng-show is used the div is displayed for few moments and then disappearing . It should not display at all for userType2

Comment: If you're not using jQuery, why did you tag your question with it?

Comment: @Sterling Archer it has been removed

Comment: if the element is not there, how can you reference it?

Comment: `myCheck` in `$scope` needs to be `mycheck`...its typo

Comment: Pengyy answer is right, but you should consider do things in a more angular way. If you use ng-model in your input[radio], you wont need the gigantic if..else if block... you can see a practical example in angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: @RonyLoud fixed the typo , used ng-show instead of ng-if as Pengyy suggested but the div first got displayed ( in userType1 which is the type that will be able to see the div) but then the div disappeared

Comment: @Xavero can you show how to use ng-model in this piece of code ?

Comment: <input type="radio" id="starRating1" name="rate" value="1" 
disabled ng-model="Item.starRating">

Answer (score 5):

With `ng-if`, the elements will be removed from DOM when the expression is false.
documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

This will cause `document.getElementById()` to get nothing back.
Consider your situation, you should try `ng-show` instead.

```
<div class="rate animated rubberBand" ng-cloak ng-show="mycheck">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: can you please tell how ?

Comment: can I use the userType checking in the script file with ng-show in the same way as I am doing with ng-if?

Comment: @msm0204 yes, almost the same way.

Comment: in this code when i replaced ng-if with ng-show the div first got displayed ( in userType1 which is the type that will be able to see the div) but then the div disappeared

Comment: @msm0204 seems your app will take sometime to load, try adding `ng-cloak` to your `div`.

Comment: I am not familiar with ng-cloak . Can you show me how to use it in  my code?

Comment: @msm0204 well, sample code updated. You should know that there is no differences between ng-if and ng-show except removing elements from DOM.

Comment: now the problem is fixed with userType1 in which the div show      but now I am facing problem with userType2 in which the div should not display. Here in userType2 inspite of myCheck being false and irrespective of whether ng-show or both ng-cloak and ng-show is used the div is displayed for few moments and then disappearing . It should not display at all for userType2

Comment: @msm0204 sorry for the late response, let's talk here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141927/angularjs-ng-show

Comment: I can't join chat , I am a new user. Stack is not allowing me to chat because of  low points

Comment: @msm0204  oh, sorry I didn't mention that.. Do you have separate code blocks for `userType1` and `userType2`?

Comment: you are on the right course. I can't accept the other 2 answers because they are setting userType in the controller. I can't do that. I just have to stop the appearance of the div in userType which is showing for say 2 seconds and then disappearing

Comment: I am using this - if (userType === 'userType2')
    {
        $scope.myCheck = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.myCheck = true;
    }

Comment: @msm0204 can you post the entire code block of your controller for I think this is caused by other issues.

Comment: @msm0204 or maybe can you tell me when will the `userType` change?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$log) {
$scope.userType = 'userType1';
$scope.mycheck = true;
$scope.change=function(){
if ($scope.userType == 'userType2')
    {
        $scope.mycheck = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.mycheck = true;
    }
    //$log.info($scope.userType);
}

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
 <select ng-model="userType" ng-change="change()">
            <option value="userType1">userType1</option>
            <option value="userType2">userType2</option>
            </select>
<div class="rate animated rubberBand"   ng-if="mycheck">
            <input type="radio" id="starRating5" name="rate" value="5" disabled>
            <label for="star5" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating4" name="rate" value="4" disabled>
            <label for="star4" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating3" name="rate" value="3" disabled>
            <label for="star3" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating2" name="rate" value="2" disabled>
            <label for="star2" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating1" name="rate" value="1" disabled>
            <label for="star1" title="text"></label>
            </div>
           
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I cannot use this - $scope.userType = 'userType1'; in my app. Because I must have to put if-else block for usertype check . Because I am to set other conditions in the if -else block which I have not written in the question section for the sake of simplicity

Comment: the only problem I am getting with Pengyy's solution - the problem is fixed with userType1 in which the div show but now I am facing problem with userType2 in which the div should not display. Here in userType2 inspite of myCheck being false and irrespective of whether ng-show or both ng-cloak and ng-show is used the div is displayed for few moments and then disappearing . It should not display at all for userType2

Answer (score 0):

You need to way to track the userType changes, this is only for handling userType when controller load

```
$scope.userType = 'userType1';

if ($scope.userType=== 'userType2')
    {
        $scope.myCheck = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.myCheck = true;
    }
```

So you need to add $watch to watch the userType changes

```
    $scope.$watchCollection("userType ", function(newVal, oldVal){

      $scope.userType = newVal;
       if ($scope.userType=== 'userType2')
        {
            $scope.myCheck = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.myCheck = true;
        }

      }
```